# Is it possible to use the NetLogo Controlling API to remote control an *running* instance of NetLogo?

Tags: python, api, netlogo

I'm exploring the use of the NetLogo Controlling API to allow an external app to pass commands to NetLogo.

When connecting to the app (I'm using PyNetLogo, but believe this is probably a general question about the API) it launches a new version of NetLogo.

Can I connect to an instance of NetLogo that is already running? If so, how?

I'm looking to connect to an *existing* instance and open models and run procedures (e.g. `start`, `go`).